# JQuery Button Data Returning As Null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button and when I click it, I want the html object (aka button) to be passed as a parameter to another javascript function. I want the javascript function to print the data-hi from the element in the button.

## HTML BUTTON

```
<button type = "button" onclick = "whoIsRdns(this)" class="dns-information btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target = "#whois_rdns_modal" data-path="{{ path( '_who_is_rdns', { 'peer': peer.number, 'ip': peer.mac } ) }}" data-hi = "hi2">
<i class="icon-search"></i>
</button>
```

## JS FUNCTION(W/ JQUERY)

```
    function whoIsRdns(thisButton){

    //Enable jQuery properties from the param of the HTML object
        var btn = $(thisButton);

        var test = btn.data('hi');
        console.log('Value is ' + test);

}
```

Why would test return as null?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `var btn = $("thisButton");` be `var btn = $(thisButton);` (without quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo

```
$("thisButton") !== $(thisButton);
```

drop the quotes so you are not looking for an element with a tag name `thisButton`

```
var btn = $("thisButton");
```

needs to be

```
var btn = $(thisButton);
```

Comment: I realize that now. Thanks!!